# Going backwards in a matched string in Javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, match, backtracking

In my application,id attribute of HTML elements should begin with #..
According to HTML5 ,the only restriction in id attribute is that ,it should not contain any whitespaces and should be atleast one character long..
So i wrote the following regular expression which matches an id attribute according to the above said constraints

```
idMatch: /^#\S+$/
```

Now i want to remove the # character in the beginning of string...
My question is , can i do both the operations in one regular expression...ie..
can i extract the characters after first '#'(characters may contain any nonwhitespace character including '#') in a string matching the above said constraints using a single regular expression.The result of match should do two things 
1)Identify id string from a set of strings (ids begin with # and follows HTML5 id naming rules)
2)Extract the part of the recognized string after first #..

Comment: HTML elements "id" attrubute should never have a "#" in them IF you want them to remain backwards compatible.

Comment: no my id selector constratint is that id strings start with # and follows html5 id rules..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parentheses in RegExes to do what you want.

```
/^#(\S+$)/.test(testString);
var idWithoutHash = RegExp.$1;
```

Comment: It's the first back-reference value captured by the parentheses ``()``. You can have up to nine back-references in a RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet that do it, just do your regex text in replace method so if it matches it returns the id without the #. Create a little helper function to make it easier to use.

```
var regex = /^#\S+$/,
    id = '#foo',
    str;

str = id.replace(regex, function($1) {
    return $1.split('#').join('');
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: i know this method...I just asked whether it is possible using regular expression only...I heard something called backtracking in regexs ..

Comment: backtracking is not supported by JS

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html -  see section titled "Important Notes About Lookbehind"